# Is there any way to change BitmapImage size in code? (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, bitmapimage

Is there any way to change BitmapImage size in code? (Silverlight)

Comment: care to explain what do you mean by "change size"?

Answer (score 1):

You may try [this approach](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/168783/380543.aspx). Do you need to support a specific Silverlight version?

EDIT: I have found [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) to be really versatile and useful. Look at teichgraf's reply in the same thread for an example of how to use it.

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: Unfortunately, I was unable to connect WriteableBitmapEx to my project.

Comment: >>Do you need to support a specific Silverlight version?
Yes, 4.0

Comment: Can you please explain "unable to connect WriteableBitmapEx to my project"? Have you added a reference to the DLL in your project?